# How to rearrange div boxes with js written children, following given array?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to making a list, in which it calculate the sum of select numbers.
There are actually over 300 items, so I limited to 6 here.
Generally, the "Image with name" adding, Change Language, Calculations all works.
I also tried the "arrange buttons" in small scale, for which it also works.
But when I add the "rearrange" buttons for the list, the page just keep refreshing back to its original way.
Is there a way to do the rearrange DIV trick?
(By the way, this seems to be working on Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but just never works on IE/Edge)

```js
let imgList = [{
    name: 30001,
    file: 'icon/30001.gif',
    jpName = 'ア',
    engName = 'alpha'
  },
  {
    name: 30002,
    file: 'icon/30002.jpg',
    jpName = 'イ',
    engName = 'beta'
  },
  (name: 40001, file: 'icon/40001.gif', jpName = 'ウ',
    engName = 'gamma'
  },
  {
    name: 41002,
    file: 'icon/41002.jpg',
    jpName = 'エ',
    engName = 'delta'
  },
  {
    name: 50301,
    file: 'icon/50301.jpg',
    jpName = 'オ',
    engName = 'mu'
  },
  {
    name: 50401,
    file: 'icon/50401.jpg',
    jpName = 'ン',
    engName = 'nu'
  }
];

//Language Controler
let control = [{
    name: 'jp',
    title: '計算',
    ans: '答え'
  },
  {
    name: 'eng',
    title: 'Calculations',
    ans: 'Answer'
  }
]

//Array Lists
let ArrayOne = ['test30001', 'test30002', 'test40001', 'test41002', 'test50301', 'test50401'];
let ArrayTwo = ['test50301', 'test50401', 'test40001', 'test41002', 'test30001', 'test30002'];
let ArrayThree = ['test30001', 'test40001', 'test50301', 'test50401', 'test30002', 'test41002'];

//Give images and name
function goImage(arr) {
  let x = imgList.findIndex(num => num['name'] === arr);
  document.getElementById('art' + arr).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgList[x].file + '"><br>' + imgList[x][language + 'Name'];
}


//Change page language
function placeAll() {
  let tb = control.findIndex(lang => lang['name'] === language);

  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = control[tb].title;
  document.getElementById('totalName').innerHTML = control[tb].ans;

  imgList.forEach(nameFile => {
    goImage(nameFile.name)
  });
}

//when select other languages
let language = 'jp';

function handleLang(myRadio) {
  language = myRadio.value;
  placeAll();
}

//amount calculations
function calculate() {
  var calValue = 0;

  countThese.each(function() {
    calValue += +$(this).val();
  })

  localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());

  let allRate = imgList.length * 10;

  document.getElementById('totalAm').innerHTML = ((calValue / allRate) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
}

let countThese = $('#testBox:input').click(calculate);

//rearrange div boxes
function ArrayOne() {
  $('#testBox div').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ArrayOne) == -1) {
      $('#testBox').append($('#' + $(this).attr('id')));
    }
  });
};

function ArrayTwo() {
  $('#testBox div').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ArrayTwo) == -1) {
      $('#testBox').append($('#' + $(this).attr('id')));
    }
  });
};

function ArrayThree() {
  $('#testBox div').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ArrayThree) == -1) {
      $('#testBox').append($('#' + $(this).attr('id')));
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<div id='title'></div>
<form id="calcul">
  <div class="container" id="testBox">

    <div class="tryBox" id="test30001">
      <div id="art30001" class="star3">
      </div>
      <div id="ca30001" class="calLV3">
        <select id="t30001" class="sLV3">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="0">1</option>
          <option value="0">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test30002">
      <div id="art30002" class="star3">
      </div>
      <div id="ca30002" class="calLV3">
        <select id="t30002" class="sLV3">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test40001">
      <div id="art40001" class="star4">
      </div>
      <div id="ca40001" class="calLV4">
        <select id="t40001" class="sLV4">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test41002">
      <div id="art41002" class="star4">
      </div>
      <div id="ca41002" class="calLV4">
        <select id="t41002" class="sLV4">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test50301">
      <div id="art50301" class="star5">
      </div>
      <div id="ca50301" class="calLV5">
        <select id="t50301" class="sLV5">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test50401">
      <div id="art50401" class="star5">
      </div>
      <div id="ca50401" class="calLV5">
        <select id="t50401" class="sLV5">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>

<div id='button1'>
  <button onclick="ArrayOne()">WAY1</button>
  <button onclick="ArrayTwo()">WAY2</button>
  <button onclick="ArrayThree()">WAY3</button>
</div>

<div id='lang'>
  <input type="radio" id="jp" name="lang" value="jp" onchange="handleLang(this)" checked>
  <label for="jp">日本語</label>
  <input type="radio" id="eng" name="lang" value="eng" onchange="handleLang(this)">
  <label for="eng">English</label>
</div>

<div class="answer">
  <div class="totalName" id="totalName"></div>
  <div class="totalAm" id="totalAm"></div>
</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: your code doesn't run.  you use `=` inside your object map declarations, and you redeclare `let ArrayOne`, among other bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax problems, like `=` in your object map declarations, redeclaration of `ArrayOne` as a function, and a `(` in your object map.

You are iterating over the HTML elements in the order that they appear, and searching the array each time as a filter.  If you want them to be in the order that the array indicates, you should be iterating in order over the array.
Or you have to account for the array index while you append, and insert them in the right position, which is more involved.  The easiest would be to use CSS `flex` and `order: (number)`

Also, `id`s should be unique to the document, so searching into #testBox and then finding the `id` that you want should not be necessary.  You should be able to use the `#id` selector directly.  I have kept the selectors as `$('#testBox div#'+id)`, just to match your original code, but it should really be just `$('#'+id')` or `document.getElementById(id)`

```js
let imgList = [{
    name: 30001,
    file: 'icon/30001.gif',
    jpName: 'ア',
    engName: 'alpha'
  },
  {
    name: 30002,
    file: 'icon/30002.jpg',
    jpName: 'イ',
    engName: 'beta'
  },
  {name: 40001, file: 'icon/40001.gif', jpName: 'ウ',
    engName: 'gamma'
  },
  {
    name: 41002,
    file: 'icon/41002.jpg',
    jpName: 'エ',
    engName: 'delta'
  },
  {
    name: 50301,
    file: 'icon/50301.jpg',
    jpName: 'オ',
    engName: 'mu'
  },
  {
    name: 50401,
    file: 'icon/50401.jpg',
    jpName: 'ン',
    engName: 'nu'
  }
];

//Language Controler
let control = [{
    name: 'jp',
    title: '計算',
    ans: '答え'
  },
  {
    name: 'eng',
    title: 'Calculations',
    ans: 'Answer'
  }
]

//Array Lists
let ArrayOne = ['test30001', 'test30002', 'test40001', 'test41002', 'test50301', 'test50401'];
let ArrayTwo = ['test50301', 'test50401', 'test40001', 'test41002', 'test30001', 'test30002'];
let ArrayThree = ['test30001', 'test40001', 'test50301', 'test50401', 'test30002', 'test41002'];

//Give images and name
function goImage(arr) {
  let x = imgList.findIndex(num => num['name'] === arr);
  document.getElementById('art' + arr).innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgList[x].file + '"><br>' + imgList[x][language + 'Name'];
}


//Change page language
function placeAll() {
  let tb = control.findIndex(lang => lang['name'] === language);

  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = control[tb].title;
  document.getElementById('totalName').innerHTML = control[tb].ans;

  imgList.forEach(nameFile => {
    goImage(nameFile.name)
  });
}

//when select other languages
let language = 'jp';

function handleLang(myRadio) {
  language = myRadio.value;
  placeAll();
}

//amount calculations
function calculate() {
  var calValue = 0;

  countThese.each(function() {
    calValue += +$(this).val();
  })

  localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());

  let allRate = imgList.length * 10;

  document.getElementById('totalAm').innerHTML = ((calValue / allRate) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
}

let countThese = $('#testBox:input').click(calculate);

//rearrange div boxes
function ArrayOne1() {
  $(ArrayOne).each(function() {
    $('#testBox').append(
      $('#testBox div#'+this)
    );
  });
/*  $('#testBox div').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ArrayOne) == -1) {
      $('#testBox').append($('#' + $(this).attr('id')));
    }
  });*/
};

function ArrayTwo1() {
  $(ArrayTwo).each(function() {
    $('#testBox').append(
      $('#testBox div#'+this)
    );
  });
  /*
  $('#testBox div').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ArrayTwo) == -1) {
      $('#testBox').append($('#' + $(this).attr('id')));
    }
  });*/
};

function ArrayThree1() {
  $(ArrayThree).each(function() {
    $('#testBox').append(
      $('#testBox div#'+this)
    );
  });
/*  $('#testBox div').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ArrayThree) == -1) {
      $('#testBox').append($('#' + $(this).attr('id')));
    }
  });*/
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='title'></div>
<form id="calcul">
  <div class="container" id="testBox">

    <div class="tryBox" id="test30001">
      <div id="art30001" class="star3">
      </div>
      <div id="ca30001" class="calLV3">
        <select id="t30001" class="sLV3">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="0">1</option>
          <option value="0">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test30002">
      <div id="art30002" class="star3">
      </div>
      <div id="ca30002" class="calLV3">
        <select id="t30002" class="sLV3">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test40001">
      <div id="art40001" class="star4">
      </div>
      <div id="ca40001" class="calLV4">
        <select id="t40001" class="sLV4">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test41002">
      <div id="art41002" class="star4">
      </div>
      <div id="ca41002" class="calLV4">
        <select id="t41002" class="sLV4">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test50301">
      <div id="art50301" class="star5">
      </div>
      <div id="ca50301" class="calLV5">
        <select id="t50301" class="sLV5">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tryBox" id="test50401">
      <div id="art50401" class="star5">
      </div>
      <div id="ca50401" class="calLV5">
        <select id="t50401" class="sLV5">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>

<div id='button1'>
  <button onclick="ArrayOne1()">WAY1</button>
  <button onclick="ArrayTwo1()">WAY2</button>
  <button onclick="ArrayThree1()">WAY3</button>
</div>

<div id='lang'>
  <input type="radio" id="jp" name="lang" value="jp" onchange="handleLang(this)" checked>
  <label for="jp">日本語</label>
  <input type="radio" id="eng" name="lang" value="eng" onchange="handleLang(this)">
  <label for="eng">English</label>
</div>

<div class="answer">
  <div class="totalName" id="totalName"></div>
  <div class="totalAm" id="totalAm"></div>
</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Next time you post a question, post working code, and a more specific description of what you want.  Your description of what you want for "rearrange DIV trick" is unclear.  Another solution, depending on the logic you want, would have been to use CSS `flex` items, and attach the order you want as styles based on the index in the array that you find the item at.

Comment: Thank you very much. This are totally new language to me, and it is really frustrating after taking weeks in a project, which should not have been so complicated. I just don't get it, why does the Workable separate part unable to go together...I will check the use of flex. But since new tryBox may added in between in the future, I am not sure if it is a good way to arrange by flex or not.

Comment: You said you need to support IE, so I don't know if flex will work well for you.  There is a polyfill called "flexibility" for IE8+.  I'd give you recommendations, but I don't know what you're planning to do, so it's difficult to give you one.  I don't know if this answer fit what you were looking for?

Comment: The rearrange function works well here, so I believe it is what I need. I just still have to figure out the problems, that when I put the code back to the original long list, the resort happened a moment, and then the whole page just refresh and go back to its original placement. Probably the the placeAll() Language and goImage() function is not written properly, but those are the parts often making the whole page blank when I tried to correct them just a little bit...